# pthread_cleanup_push causes Syntax error

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I try to add a section to my code which is able to unlock the mutex in a case of cancellation. This may happen and would cause a deadlock. Therefore I tried to add `pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup_unlock_mutex, &mutex_ftdi);` but this line cause a syntax error from the line where I add it till the end of the code file. If I comment the code line the program will compile without any error. 
What I'm doing wrong?

```
void cleanup_unlock_mutex(void *p){
    pthread_mutex_unlock(p);
}

....... }else{
                for(unsigned count=0; count <= number_of_requests; count++){
                    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup_unlock_mutex, &mutex_ftdi);
                    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_ftdi);
                    process_requests(count, numberofthread);
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_ftdi);
                }
            } // compiler error: error: expected ‘while’ before ‘}’ token
..........
```

All other functions in the file get the warning: ISO C forbids nested functions [-pedantic].

Comment: `}` missed. can you indent code first? strange!!!!  `else` without `if`? where is `while` loop? post whole code.

Comment: There is no strange else, but I do not want to post the if section of the code. The code works perfect. If I add the line `pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup_unlock_mutex, &mutex_ftdi);` it is no longer compilable. If comment this line or remove it everything works. But I cannot spot any error and I do not remove or add any `{ }`

Comment: `but I do not want to post the if section of the code.` if you not want then anyone not want give you answer.

Comment: You don't get the point. The problem is not the code, the problem is caused by this line.

Comment: You not get the point. look error first.

Comment: I got the point. But I will explain it again for you: If I add this line to the code: `pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup_unlock_mutex, &mutex_ftdi);`. Then the code is no longer compilable. The compiler shows errors and warnings. After I comment the line `\\pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup_unlock_mutex, &mutex_ftdi);` everything works fine. Therefore the problem is this line. Maybe I need to add a compiler flag or anything else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56575/discussion-between-irgendw-pointer-and-jayesh).

Comment: @IrgendwPointer : I believe you that only the `pthread` line of code is causing problem that's why you don't want to show your code, but please consider showing a compilable/runnable piece of code, in order that any person can try to find your error and gives you back an answer

Comment: @chouaib you were right and I just found the solution which Michael Burr postet as answer. So that was the problem and it is solved now.

Comment: Why was this question closed? It clearly has enough information to diagnose and answer. It's probably even helpful to someone who might run into the same problem.

Comment: This is a duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20304366/694576

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You must call `pthread_cleanup_push()` and `pthread_cleanup_pop()` in matching pairs, and your snippet doesn't have the `pthread_cleanup_pop()` call.

The docs at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cleanup_pop.html explain why:

> These functions may be implemented as macros. The application shall
>   ensure that they appear as statements, and in pairs within the same
>   lexical scope (that is, the `pthread_cleanup_push()` macro may be
>   thought to expand to a token list whose first token is `'{'` with
>   `pthread_cleanup_pop()` expanding to a token list whose last token is
>   the corresponding `'}'` ).

To make this concrete, one possible implementation, taken from glibc's `nptl/sysdeps/pthread/pthread.h`:

```
/* Install a cleanup handler: ROUTINE will be called with arguments ARG
   when the thread is canceled or calls pthread_exit.  ROUTINE will also
   be called with arguments ARG when the matching pthread_cleanup_pop
   is executed with non-zero EXECUTE argument.

   pthread_cleanup_push and pthread_cleanup_pop are macros and must always
   be used in matching pairs at the same nesting level of braces.  */
#  define pthread_cleanup_push(routine, arg) \
  do {                                        \
    __pthread_cleanup_class __clframe (routine, arg)

/* Remove a cleanup handler installed by the matching pthread_cleanup_push.
   If EXECUTE is non-zero, the handler function is called. */
#  define pthread_cleanup_pop(execute) \
    __clframe.__setdoit (execute);                        \
  } while (0)
```

Comment: Still useful 8 years later.  Thanks!